# Nested for loops over arrays with different lengths and generating files accordingly

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested

I have two files: `V1.out` and `V2.out`:

They both have the following structure: Each file contains three variables: `VOLUME`, `EL` and `E0`. Additionally, for each temperature `T`, there is a value of `ET` and `TS` associated:

`V1.out`:

```
LATTICE PARAMETERS  (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - PRIMITIVE CELL
       A          B          C        ALPHA      BETA     GAMMA        VOLUME
    6.08566    5.03702    7.64745    90.00000 105.09618  90.00000    226.331804

                          AU/CELL
 EL            :   -3765.004233655181
 E0            :       0.073893382446

 TEMPERATURE FOR THERMO ANALYSIS   10.00 KELVIN - 2000.00 KELVIN (POINTS4)

 AT (T =   10.00 K, P =   0.10132500E+00 MPA):

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 ET            :       0.000000028637       0.000000779258           0.00007519
 TS            :       0.000000031491       0.000000856925           0.00008268


 AT (T =   30.10 K, P =   0.10132500E+00 MPA):

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 ET            :       0.000035934511       0.000977827744           0.09434604
 TS            :       0.000045071597       0.001226460503           0.11833546


 AT (T =   50.20 K, P =   0.10132500E+00 MPA):

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 ET            :       0.000247740762       0.006741368865           0.65044328
 TS            :       0.000333253672       0.009068293427           0.87495739


 AT (T =   70.30 K, P =   0.10132500E+00 MPA):

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 ET            :       0.000711121913       0.019350611008           1.86705032
 TS            :       0.001003762120       0.027313755902           2.63537708
```

`V2.out`:

```
 LATTICE PARAMETERS  (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - PRIMITIVE CELL
       A          B          C        ALPHA      BETA     GAMMA        VOLUME
    6.13522    5.04903    7.66206    90.00000 105.40656  90.00000    228.817957

 TEMPERATURE FOR THERMO ANALYSIS   10.00 KELVIN - 2000.00 KELVIN (POINTS4)

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 EL            :   -3765.007272400268 -102451.056393071922    -9885025.20063421
 E0            :       0.073470147948       1.999224364265         192.89584625

 AT (T =   10.00 K, P =   0.10132500E+00 MPA):

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 ET            :       0.000000041695       0.000001134585           0.00010947
 TS            :       0.000000046017       0.000001252179           0.00012082


 AT (T =   30.10 K, P =   0.10132500E+00 MPA):

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 ET            :       0.000040732367       0.001108384059           0.10694281
 TS            :       0.000051455315       0.001400170298           0.13509591

 AT (T =   50.20 K, P =   0.10132500E+00 MPA):

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 ET            :       0.000266315355       0.007246809228           0.69921087
 TS            :       0.000361155871       0.009827550878           0.94821461

 AT (T =   70.30 K, P =   0.10132500E+00 MPA):

                          AU/CELL             EV/CELL                 KJ/MOL
 ET            :       0.000747534260       0.020341441355           1.96265092
 TS            :       0.001063768303       0.028946607140           2.79292329
```

I would like to create four files:

```
T_10.00K.dat
T_30.10K.dat
T_50.20K.dat
T_70.30K.dat
```

That would contain:

```
T_10.00.dat                       |    T_30.10.dat                 |    T_50.20.dat                  |    T_70.30.dat
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------
VOLUME:           F:              | VOLUME:           F:           | VOLUME:           F:            | VOLUME:           F:
                                  |                                |                                 |
V1              F(V1, T=10.00)    | V1              F(V1, T=30.10) | V1              F(V1, T=50.20)  | V1              F(V1, T=70.30)
V2              F(V2, T=10.00)    | V2              F(V2, T=30.10) | V2              F(V2, T=50.20)  | V2              F(V2, T=70.30)
```

where for a particular temperature and volume, the variable `F` is obtained as:

```
F = EL + E0 + ET -TS
```

I have been able to extract each `EL`, `E0` variables; in addition to the 
`ET` and `TS` variables for each temperature:

```
import re
import os
import glob
from itertools import islice
import numpy as np
import sys

n_volume = []
path='./'
template = os.path.join(path, '*.out')


# Extracting each thermodynamic variable:
ET = []
TS = []
EL = []
E0 = []
VOLUME_EACH = []
T = []

for fname in glob.glob(template):
  print fname
  f = open(fname, 'r')
  real_part = False

  for line in f:

        if re.match(r"^ ET            :", line):
         start = line.find(':') + 8
         end = line.find(':') + 22
         result_ET = line[start:end]
         ET.append(result_ET)

        if re.match(r"^ TS            :", line):
         start = line.find(':') + 8
         end = line.find(':') + 22
         result_TS = line[start:end]
         TS.append(result_TS)

        if re.match(r"^ EL            :", line):
         start = line.find(':') + 4
         end = line.find(':') + 22
         result_EL = line[start:end]
         EL.append(result_EL)

        if re.match(r"^ E0            :", line):
         start = line.find(':') + 8
         end = line.find(':') + 22
         result_E0 = line[start:end]
         E0.append(result_E0)

        if re.match(r"^ AT \(T =", line):
         start = line.find('T =') + 4
         end = line.find('K')
         result_Temperatures = line[start:end]
         T.append(result_Temperatures)

        if 'LATTICE PARAMETERS  (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - PRIMITIVE CELL' in line:
                  print "line 1 = ", line
                  f.next()
                  each_volume_times_4 = []
                  each_volume_times_100 = []

                  parameters = (''.join(islice(f, 1)))
                  columns = parameters.split()
                  each_volume = columns[6]
                  print 'each_volume = ', each_volume

                  VOLUME_EACH.append(each_volume)

# Transform each element of the list from <str> to <float64>:
VOLUME_EACH = [float(i) for i in VOLUME_EACH]
EL = [float(i) for i in EL]
E0 = [float(i) for i in E0]
ET = [float(i) for i in ET]
TS = [float(i) for i in TS]
T = [float(i) for i in T]

# Transform each element of the list to a numpy array:
VOLUME_EACH = np.array(VOLUME_EACH)
EL = np.array(EL)
E0 = np.array(E0)
ET = np.array(ET)
TS = np.array(TS)
T = np.array(T)

print 'VOLUME_EACH = ', VOLUME_EACH
print 'len(VOLUME_EACH) =  ' , len(VOLUME_EACH)

print 'EL = ', EL
print 'len(EL) =  ' , len(EL)

print 'E0 = ', E0
print 'len(E0) =  ' , len(E0)

print 'T = ', T
print 'len(T) =  ' , len(T)

print 'ET = ', ET
print 'len(ET) =  ' , len(ET)

print 'TS = ', TS
print 'len(TS) =  ' , len(TS)

F_ALL = []
for Vols in VOLUME_EACH:
   aux = []
   for Ts, (ETs, TSs) in enumerate(zip(ET, TS)):
      F_for_each_Vol = EL + E0 + ET - TS
      aux.append(F_for_each_Vol)
F_ALL.append(aux)

print  F_ALL
```

The error received is the following:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (8,)

This is because, as stated in the final print statements:

```
VOLUME_EACH =  [ 226.331804  228.817957]
len(VOLUME_EACH) =   2
EL =  [-3765.00423366 -3765.0072724 ]
len(EL) =   2
E0 =  [ 0.07389338  0.07347015]
len(E0) =   2
T =  [ 10.   30.1  50.2  70.3  10.   30.1  50.2  70.3]
len(T) =   8
ET =  [  2.86370000e-08   3.59345110e-05   2.47740762e-04   7.11121913e-04
   4.16950000e-08   4.07323670e-05   2.66315355e-04   7.47534260e-04]
len(ET) =   8
TS =  [  3.14910000e-08   4.50715970e-05   3.33253672e-04   1.00376212e-03
   4.60170000e-08   5.14553150e-05   3.61155871e-04   1.06376830e-03]
len(TS) =   8
```

it happens that `T`, the Temperature array, contains the temperatures from both `V1.dat` and `V2.dat`.

The `ET` and `TS` variables are different at each temperature for each `VOLUME`. The best way I could think is to extract these is by using a 1-D array. However, this yields a mismatch on the lengths.

How could `ET` and `TS`  variables be better extracted in order to avoid the above mismatch?

For example, for `V1.dat` we have, for T=10.00k, the following info:

```
VOLUME = 226.331804
EL            :   -3765.004233655181
E0            :       0.073893382446
ET            :       0.000000028637
TS            :       0.000000031491
```

If we sum up manually we get:

> F(V1, T=10.00) = -3765.004233655181 + 0.073893382446 +  0.000000028637 - 0.000000031491 = -3764.93034027559

Comment: Check your indentation. as shown, F_ALL would only contain a single element

Comment: @kdopen Thanks for your comment. Please see updated post